# How to display the field using javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inputfield

I have 4 fields: 1)Gender__c 2) Date_of_birth__c 3) Age__c 4) Field4__c

**My condition is: If (Gender__c='Female' & Age__c>12)
Then display the field4__c.**

I tried with the following code, It is displaying When I select the gender='female' & if I enter the value manually which meets the 
condition: age>12 .

**I wrote another Javascript with @RemoteAction to update Age__c when I select the Date_of_birth__c.**

**It is not displaying the field4__c, If the Age__c is updated from date_of_birth__c.**

**Code is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var displayField4 = function() {
        var genderVal   = $( "[id*='inpFldGender']" ).val();
        var ageVal      = $( "[id*='inpFldAge']" ).val();

        if( genderVal === 'Female' && ageVal > 12 ) {
            $( "[id*='inpFld4']" ).show();
            $( "[for*='inpFld4']" ).show();
        }
        else {
            $( "[id*='inpFld4']" ).hide();
            $( "[for*='inpFld4']" ).hide();
        }
    };

    displayField4();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field update is called from the `onchange` event, you need to trigger it manually if you update fields via javascript.  `jQuery` has the [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to do this.

Also, your function can be made quite a bit simpler with [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
var displayField4 = function() {
    var genderVal   = $( "[id*='inpFldGender']" ).val();
    var ageVal      = $( "[id*='inpFldAge']" ).val();

    $( "[id*='inpFld4'], [for*='inpFld4']" ).toggle(genderVal === 'Female' && ageVal > 12);
};
```

Comment: I tried with above code. Not displaying.

Comment: Have you verified your `displayField4` function is actually called by the RemoteAction callback?

Comment: Are you using the correct selector    $( "[id$='inpFld4']" ).hide();. if you are giving id to an apex VF tag use id$ instead of id* since apex by default adds form id to the id content if its inside a form. your id  that you gave will be the last part of the id.